# How to get the number of pages in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working with [DataTables](http://datatables.net/index) and I need to know the current number of pages that a table holds (this certainly depends on the number of rows per page and the total number of rows and may change by user-action). Does anybody know how to access this value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe iTotalPages is what you're after: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnPagingInfo

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function(oSettings){
    return {
        "iTotalPages": oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
            0 : Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
    };
};    

$('#example').dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function(){
        alert('There are ' + this.fnPagingInfo().iTotalPages + ' in this table.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this for getting total number of records

```
"drawCallback": function( settings, start, end, max, total, pre ) { 
                    var info = tbl_driverList.page.info(); 
                    alert(info.recordsDisplay);
}
```